# Switch synatx error issue

Tags: vba, excel-2010

In the following vba code in excel 2010 I am getting the error message Syntax error. I think it is to do with the switch statement but can't see what is wrong. Do you know what I have done wrong?

```
Sub timeperiod()

Dim change As Integer, colA As Date, i As Long, val As String

For i = 2 To Rows.Count

colA = Cells(i, 1).Value
change = Day(Now) - Day(colA)
val = Cells(i, 3).Value

If change <= 0 Then

val = Switch(_
DATEDIF (colA, Now,"m") < 3 And DATEDIF (colA, Now,"m") > 0,'1 - 2 months',_
DATEDIF (colA, Now,"m") < 5 And DATEDIF (colA, Now,"m") > 2,'2 - 4 months',_
DATEDIF (colA, Now,"m") < 7 And DATEDIF (colA,Now,"m") > 4,'4 - 6 months',_
DATEDIF (colA, Now,"m") <10 And DATEDIF (colA, Now,"m") > 6, '6 - 9 months',_
DATEDIF (colA, Now,"m") > 9, '9 months+')

ElseIf change > 0 Then

val = Switch (_
DATEDIF (colA, Now,"m") = 2, '2 - 4 months',_
DATEDIF (colA, Now,"m") = 4, '4 - 6 months',_
DATEDIF (colA, Now,"m") = 6, '6 - 9 months',_
DATEDIF (colA, Now,"m") = 9, '9 months+',_
DATEDIF (colA, Now,"m") < 2 And DATEDIF (colA, Now,"m") > 0,'1 - 2 months',_
DATEDIF (colA, Now,"m") < 4 And DATEDIF (colA, Now,"m") > 2,  '2 - 4 months',_
DATEDIF (colA, Now,"m") < 6 And DATEDIF (colA, Now,"m") > 4,  '4 - 6 months',_
DATEDIF (colA, Now,"m") < 9 And DATEDIF (colA, Now,"m") > 6, '6 - 9 months',_
DATEDIF (colA, Now,"m") > 9, '9 months+')

End If
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `Switch` is not available in excel 2010, use `Select .. Case` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several problems:

---

Use `_` to continue lines:

```
val = switch( _
    ...
```

the space before `_` is important (to enable variable names containing `_` I guess?). You also can't comment except after the last segment

---

use double quotes `"` to create strings, single quotes `'` are for comments.

---

use `DateDiff` in VBA. Usage `DateDiff(Interval, Date1, Date2)`

```
DateDiff ("m", colA, Now)
```

---

However, as Tensibai noted, a `Select ... Case` would be nicer here:

```
Select Case DateDiff("m", colA, Now)
    Case 1 to 2
        val = "1 - 2 months"
    Case 3 to 4
        val = "2 - 4 months"
    '...
    Case Is > 9
        val = "9+ months"
End Select
```

Comment: ...the minute i posted it... ;)

Answer (score 3):

`Tensibai` is right in the regard `SELECT...CASE` might be better in this case, however, there is a `SWITCH`-Function in VBA.

There are some small mistakes in your syntax:

1. Its `DateDiff` not `DATEDIF`
2. In VBA you have to use double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'` to start and escape strings. Single quotes are used for commenting
3. `DateDiff`-Syntax is `DateDiff(Interval, Date1, Date2)`, so you mixed the arguments up a bit

As for your code:

```
Sub timeperiod()

Dim change As Integer, colA As Date, i As Long, val As String

For i = 2 To Rows.Count

    colA = Cells(i, 1).Value
    change = Day(Now) - Day(colA)
    val = Cells(i, 3).Value

    If change <= 0 Then

        Debug.Print DateDiff("M", colA, Now)
        Select Case DateDiff("M", colA, Now)
            Case 1 To 2: val = "1 - 2 months"
            Case 2 To 4: val = "2 - 4 months"
            Case Is > 9: val = "9 months"
            ' and so on
            Case Else: val = "not categorized"
        End Select
    ElseIf change > 0 Then

    ' your code....

    End If

    Debug.Print val

Next i
```

End Sub

Answer (score 2):

your syntax errors has been properly described by Martin and acradeprecinct, so I here concentrate on the logic

[Switch()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264257(v=office.15).aspx) function evaluates expressions from left to right and stops at the first one evaluated as `True`.

you can exploit this and shorten down your code as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub timeperiod()
    Dim change As Integer, colA As Date, i As Long, val As String
    Dim dateDif As Long

    For i = 2 To Rows.Count
        colA = Cells(i, 1).value
        dateDif = DateDiff("m", colA, Now)
        change = Day(Now) - Day(colA)
        If change <= 0 Then
            val = Switch(dateDif <= 0, "Error", _
                         dateDif < 3, "1 - 2 months", _
                         dateDif < 5, "2 - 4 months", _
                         dateDif < 7, "4 - 6 months", _
                         dateDif < 10, "6 - 9 months", _
                         dateDif >= 10, "9 months+")

        ElseIf change > 0 Then
            val = Switch(dateDif < 0, "Error", _
                         dateDif < 2, "1 - 2 months", _
                         dateDif < 4, "2 - 4 months", _
                         dateDif < 6, "4 - 6 months", _
                         dateDif < 9, "6 - 9 months", _
                         dateDif >= 9, "9 months+")
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

I'd point out that your "labels" actually overlap each other, and I think you should consider to change the first number so that for the first `Switch` it would be:

```
        val = Switch(dateDif <= 0, "", _
                     dateDif < 3, "1 - 2 months", _
                     dateDif < 5, "3 - 4 months", _
                     dateDif < 7, "5 - 6 months", _
                     dateDif < 10, "7 - 9 months", _
                     dateDif >= 10, "10 months+")
```

and similarly for the other `Switch` statement

That said you can furtherly shorten down your code once you notice that the two `Switch()` statements differ for the comparative term of `dateDif` only, in correspondence of `change` value compared to `0`

so you may code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub timeperiod()
    Dim change As Integer, colA As Date, i As Long, val As String
    Dim dateDif As Long, deltaDif As Long

    For i = 2 To Rows.Count
        colA = Cells(i, 1).value
        dateDif = DateDiff("m", colA, Now)
        change = Day(Now) - Day(colA)
        deltaDif = IIf(change <= 0, 1, 0)

        val = Switch(dateDif < 0, "Error", _
                     dateDif < 2 + deltaDif, "1 - 2 months", _
                     dateDif < 4 + deltaDif, "2 - 4 months", _
                     dateDif < 6 + deltaDif, "4 - 6 months", _
                     dateDif < 9 + deltaDif, "6 - 9 months", _
                     dateDif >= 9 + deltaDif, "9 months+")
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Why I try this it runs but the messags (eg: 1 - 2 months" etc) are not displayed in the new column. Do you know how I can print them out?

Comment: I saw you accepted an answer so I guess you're altready through it